# Hashicorp Vault and MinIO KES 403 Permission Denied When I Try to Create a Key

Tags: hashicorp-vault, minio, minio-client

I'm trying to run Hashicorp Vault and MinIO KES Server as self-hosted solutions on my server. However, I get `Error: failed to create key "my-app-1": bad gateway: failed to create key` error from client when I try to create a key. Here are my configs:

##### vault-config.json

```
{
  "api_addr": "https://vaultnew.mycompany.com:8200",
  "backend": {
    "file": {
      "path": "./data/vault/file"
    }
  },

  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "720h",

  "listener": {
    "tcp": {
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_cert_file": "/home/ubuntu/vault_certs/fullchain.pem",
      "tls_key_file": "/home/ubuntu/vault_certs/privkey.pem",
      "tls_min_version": "tls12"
    }
  }
}
```

##### kes-policy.hcl

```
path "kv/*" {
      capabilities = [ "create", "read", "delete" ]
}
```

##### config.yml

```
address: 0.0.0.0:7373 # Listen on all network interfaces on port 7373

admin:
  identity: disabled  # We disable the admin identity since we don't need it in this guide

tls:
  key: /home/ubuntu/kes_certs/privkey.pem    # The KES server TLS private key
  cert: /home/ubuntu/kes_certs/fullchain.pem    # The KES server TLS certificate

policy:
  my-app:
    allow:
    - /v1/key/create/my-app*
    - /v1/key/generate/my-app*
    - /v1/key/decrypt/my-app*
    identities:
    - <output from kes identity of minio_client_fullchain.pem>

keystore:
   vault:
     endpoint: https://vaultnew.mycompany.com:8200
     version:  v1 # The K/V engine version - either "v1" or "v2".
     approle:
       id:     "b2191d58-a86a-5b77-987d-3fa9fb92152f" # Your AppRole ID
       secret: "cd247831-97c7-cf83-b33d-9962c2e2a132" # Your AppRole Secret
       retry:  15s
     status:
       ping: 10s
```

This is the error log from KES Server:

```
2024/01/17 11:19:42 vault: failed to create 'kv/my-app-1': Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://vaultnew.mycompany.com:8200/v1/kv/my-app-1
Code: 403. Errors:

* 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

Comment: How is the entity authenticated?